# TensorFlow Extended on MacOS M1 Max Chip

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1, tensorflow-extended

I am having some issue getting TFX to work on my MacOS M1 Max chip.

I have gone through the provide instructions from Apple on how to get tensorflow to work on my machine. Unfortunately, once I attempt to get TFX installed it uses the non-macos version that fails to work as it throws an Illegal Hardware Instruction error.

As I have seen instructions on how to get TF to work on MacOS, has there been luck on getting this to work out there?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please [edit] your question and describe what you did, and what issue exactly you have? A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: I've also gone through the same issue. Seems like the solution is being worked on by the tf crew so it's now a waiting game.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact you are trying which shows `Illegal Hardware Instruction error`. Did you follow [these](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) instructions properly to install tensorflow in macOS? Attaching the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75510120/14290681) for your reference. Let us know if the issue still persists.