# Cannot start jupyter notebook with tensorflow on M1 mac

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1

To get tensorflow working on an M1 mac I installed anaconda navigator, and then [followed these instructions](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/):

install `miniforge`, and then

```
tensorflow-deps
tensorflow-macos
tensorflow-metal
```

Installing these packages did not give any errors, but when I try to launch a `Jupyter notebook` from the Anaconda Navigator interface I get this error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/../miniforge3/envs/macos-tensorflow64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/_device.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/../miniforge3/envs/macos-tensorflow64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/_device.cpython-38-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

It seems that `_device.cpython-38-darwin.so` is not ready for M1 ? Is this a bug?
How can I get tensorflow working on the M1 mac? (with a jupyter notebook). Note: I did get Jupyter notebook working with python in general, just not with tensorflow).

Comment: Could you also check the steps mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install `TensorFlow` in `miniconda` for Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks, that link leads back to here: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ but I already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have installed miniforge 'x86_64' file whereas you need 'arm64' as shown in the **ImportError** message.

Please try again by installing [miniconda macOS](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#latest-miniconda-installer-links) (`Miniconda3 macOS Apple M1 64-bit bash`) package and run below code step by step in the terminal to access the tensorflow with jupyter notebook:

- Download the miniconda package, open the terminal and cd to the
  download directory to access the miniconda.sh file 
  `cd downloads`
  `bash <the_downloaded_package.sh>` - agree(yes) to the License terms and confirm the miniconda installation directory.
- cd to the installed miniconda directory and create conda virtual environment for tensorflow

  `conda create --name tf python=3.9` 
  `conda activate tf`
- Now install **TensorFlow** using

  `pip install --upgrade pip` 
  `python -m pip install tensorflow #or`
  `python -m pip install tensorflow-macos`
  `python -m pip install tensorflow-metal`
- To verify if tensorflow installed, type:
  `python (enter)`
  `>>import tensorflow as tf`
  `>>tf.__version__`
- Install and open the jupyter notebook.

  `conda install jupyter` 
  `jupyter notebook`