# Installing TensorFlow MacBook Pro M1

Tags: macos, tensorflow, machine-learning, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I've been trying to install my tensorflow on my MacBook Pro M1. I've watched so many videos on it on YouTube.
I get to this stage smoothly without any errors.
`conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps`
But after this when I'm required to install the actual base version
`python -m pip install tensorflow-macos`
I keep getting 'zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/python3.10' every single time. I have uninstalled and reinstalled homebrew and minconda multiple times.

I have created a conda environment to install tensorflow according to most videos but it still doesn't seem to work and I keep getting that error.

Any advice? I'm trying to set up my laptop for Machine Learning and Data Science and use VSCode as the editor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are creating conda virtual environment in the same directory where miniconda has installed and then install tensorflow. Please follow the step by step [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) mentioned in the link to install `TensorFlow` in Mac M1.

You can import and use the tensorflow by accessing the **VScode** editor from Anaconda Navigator in the same VirEnv where you have installed tensorflow.

Attaching here the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75510120/14290681) to install tensorflow in Mac  for your reference.